# Problem Wraping Text Around Content

Tags: floats, minipage, wrapfigure

I am trying to put a left side content for a newsletter on my page. Looking at many stackexchange pages, I am trying wrapfigure+minipage but i can't get the text to wrap!

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}% Required for creating boxes
\mdfdefinestyle{sidebar}{
    linecolor=gray, % Outer line color
    outerlinewidth=0.0pt, % Outer line width
    roundcorner=0pt, % Amount of corner rounding
    backgroundcolor=gray, % Box background color
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=white, % Title background color
    frametitlerule=false, % Title rule - true or false
    frametitlefont=\Large, % Title heading font specification
    font=\small
}


\textwidth = 7 in % Text width
\textheight = 10 in % Text height
\oddsidemargin = -18pt % Left side margin on odd pages
\evensidemargin = -18pt % Left side margin on even pages
\topmargin = -36pt % Top margin
\headheight = 0pt % Remove the header by setting its space to 0
\headsep = 0pt % Remove the space between the header and top of the page
\parskip = 4pt % Space between paragraph
\parindent = 0.0in % Paragraph indentation
\pagestyle{empty} % Disable page numbering


%--------------------------------
%       Table of Contents
%--------------------------------

\let\Contentsline\contentsline
\renewcommand\contentsline[3]{\Contentsline{#1}{#2}{}}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hypertarget{contents}{\textbf{{\large In This Issue\ldots}}}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \ifcsname prefix@#1\endcsname
    \csname prefix@#1\endcsname
  \else
    \csname the#1\endcsname\quad
  \fi}
% define \prefix@section
\newcommand\prefix@section{}
\makeatother

\titlecontents{section}[0em]
{\vskip 0.5ex}%
{\scshape}% numbered sections formattin
{\itshape}% unnumbered sections formatting
{}%

%\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{0pt}

\begin{document}


    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.3\linewidth}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} % Mini page taking up 30% of the actual page
                \begin{mdframed}[style=sidebar,frametitle={}] % Sidebar box
        \tableofcontents
                 FOOBAR
                \end{mdframed}
        \end{minipage}%\hfill % End the sidebar mini page
    \end{wrapfigure}


\section{First section} \lipsum[1-2]
\section{Second section} \lipsum[3-4]
\section{Third section} \lipsum[5-6]
\section{Fourth section} \lipsum[7-8]
\section{Fifth section} \lipsum[9-10]
\section{Final section} \lipsum[11-12]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at the `flowfram` package.

Comment: please fix your example so that it is a complete document people can run it and see the problem and test answers, what is `\makeheader` for example?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - i have now made a version that is fully compile'able.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - in your solution, do you know why "First Section" isn't aligning with the top of the box?

Comment: @JMH the box is stuck to the invisible mbox (use `\mbox{zzzzz}` and you'll see) You can add a `\vspace` at the start of the wrapfig to move it down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to give `wrapfig` something simpler than a section heading to start on, `\mbox{}` here. I also removed the `minipage` inside the wrapfig as I couldn't see what it was intended to do.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}% Required for creating boxes
\mdfdefinestyle{sidebar}{
    linecolor=gray, % Outer line color
    outerlinewidth=0.0pt, % Outer line width
    roundcorner=0pt, % Amount of corner rounding
    backgroundcolor=gray, % Box background color
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=white, % Title background color
    frametitlerule=false, % Title rule - true or false
    frametitlefont=\Large, % Title heading font specification
    font=\small
}


\textwidth = 7 in % Text width
\textheight = 10 in % Text height
\oddsidemargin = -18pt % Left side margin on odd pages
\evensidemargin = -18pt % Left side margin on even pages
%\topmargin = -36pt % Top margin
%\headheight = 0pt % Remove the header by setting its space to 0
%\headsep = 0pt % Remove the space between the header and top of the page
\parskip = 4pt % Space between paragraph
\parindent = 0.0in % Paragraph indentation
\pagestyle{empty} % Disable page numbering


%--------------------------------
%       Table of Contents
%--------------------------------

\let\Contentsline\contentsline
\renewcommand\contentsline[3]{\Contentsline{#1}{#2}{}}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hypertarget{contents}{\textbf{{\large In This Issue\ldots}}}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \ifcsname prefix@#1\endcsname
    \csname prefix@#1\endcsname
  \else
    \csname the#1\endcsname\quad
  \fi}
% define \prefix@section
\newcommand\prefix@section{}
\makeatother

\titlecontents{section}[0em]
{\vskip 0.5ex}%
{\scshape}% numbered sections formattin
{\itshape}% unnumbered sections formatting
{}%

%\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{0pt}

\begin{document}


    \begin{wrapfigure}[10]{l}{0.3\linewidth}
                \begin{mdframed}[style=sidebar,frametitle={}] % Sidebar box
        \tableofcontents
                 FOOBAR
                \end{mdframed}
    \end{wrapfigure}
\mbox{}

\section{First section} \lipsum[1-2]
\section{Second section} \lipsum[3-4]
\section{Third section} \lipsum[5-6]
\section{Fourth section} \lipsum[7-8]
\section{Fifth section} \lipsum[9-10]
\section{Final section} \lipsum[11-12]

\end{document}
```

Comment: the minipage was a copy-paste from other code examples i found online! :)

Comment: do you know why the first section isn't aligned with the top of the wrap text?